How to modify JavaScript Request object properties?
I was asking ChatGPT and he give this code:
const originalRequest = new Request("https://example.com", {
  method: "GET",
  redirect: "follow",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});

const newRequest = new Request(originalRequest.url, {
  method: originalRequest.method,
  headers: originalRequest.headers,
  body: originalRequest.body,
  mode: originalRequest.mode,
  credentials: originalRequest.credentials,
  cache: originalRequest.cache,
  referrer: originalRequest.referrer,
  referrerPolicy: originalRequest.referrerPolicy,
  integrity: originalRequest.integrity,
  keepalive: originalRequest.keepalive,
  signal: originalRequest.signal,
  redirect: "manual"  // Changed redirect field here
});

Which is a bit ugly, when I asked how to make it use introspection, he answered that is not possible. But since chatGPT give wrong answers all the time, I was trying this code to get all properties from Request object, but it didn't work:
const request = new Request("https://example.com", {
  method: "GET",
  redirect: "follow",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(request));
// []

So I was wondering if there is any way to get props from Request object, so you can create cleaner and more generic clone Request function?

The solution is based on code by @DavidT in answer to this question:

Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?

Seems to work, but the accepted answer does not. The code use Object.getPrototypeOf and get the keys from it.
This is the full code to create a new copy of the Request object and modify properties you need.


const request = new Request('https://example.com', {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'error',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});

function clone(req, options) {
   const props = Object.assign(to_object(req), options);

   return new Request(req.url, props);
}

function to_object(req) {
   const pairs = keys(req).map(key => {
     return [key, req[key]];
   });
   return Object.fromEntries(pairs);
}

function keys(obj) {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    return Reflect.ownKeys(proto).filter(prop => {
       // we don't want functions in our final object
       return prop && typeof obj[prop] !== 'function';
    });
}

console.log(request);
console.log(clone(request, { redirect: 'follow' }));



